# Call Method from Main Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to call a method, WriteToFile, from The main method. Here is what I have so far:

```
public void main(String [ ] args)
{
    String fileLoc = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "AccelData.txt";

    File AccelData = new File(fileLoc);

    AccelData.WriteToFile(fileLoc, AccelData);
}
```

And the WriteToFile method is:

```
public void WriteToFile(String fileLoc, File AccelData){
    //code in here
}
```

I get a red line under the `AccelData.WriteToFile`line, which just says I should add a cast, which doesn't fix it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I recommend to start with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html as this is a fairly basic problem...

Comment: You are using java.io.File? Or some other?

Comment: main is a static method you can't call a non static method from a static method...........if i am wrong correct me

Comment: yes...you are trying to call a non-static method , that too, not with respect to any object. In short, you are trying to use a non-static method as a static method,which is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot apply `WriteToFile()` method to `java.io.File` instances, becuase it's not defined in standard Java File class.

One alternative way you can apply to your code is declaring your method as static:

```
public static void WriteToFile(String fileLoc, File AccelData){
    //code in here
}
```

And in the main method just call it with its name:

```
WriteToFile(fileLoc, AccelData);
```

Second way could be creating an instance of the class which encapsulates `WriteToFile()` method, and then invoking that method on your instance again in main method:

```
YourClass obj = new YourClass();
obj.WriteToFile(fileLoc, AccelData);
```

Comment: Then how can I call the Write to file method from the main? Should I move the `String fileLoc = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "AccelData.txt";

    File AccelData = new File(fileLoc);
` to the write to file method?

Comment: you can declare WriteToFile() as a static method. then you can call it from main.

Comment: I can't declare it as a static as the variables can't be static

Comment: @ELSheepO so apply my 2nd approach. read my post, it's updated.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be either calling it correctly or not creating the file

Comment: @ELSheepO the directory might not be existing or writable, check permissions and file location. Tell the error here, what is the error message?

Comment: It doesn't give a error message, it just sits there. this line that if it doesn't exist it creates it `if (!(accelData.exists()))
                {
                    accelData.createNewFile();
                }` I gave it the premission to write to external storage.

Answer (score 2):

First i would like to say that signature of your main method is not correct, it's.:

```
public static void main(String [ ] args)
 {
   // do somthing 
 }
```

Go to this link  [A Closer Look at the "Hello World!" Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html)

And second you are calling a method with its class name then that method should be `static` like following

```
public static void WriteToFile(String fileLoc, File AccelData){
 //code in here
}
```

Or you have to call that method with its class object.

```
public static void main(String [ ] args)
 {
   String fileLoc = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "AccelData.txt";

   File AccelData = new File(fileLoc);

   ClassName className= new ClassName();
   className.WriteToFile(fileLoc, AccelData);
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you can create an instance of the current class to call a non static method (although, design-wise, it shouldn't come down to this).

Comment: Your method is basically the same as what Vincenzo stated below. It doesn't seem to be calling the method, or if it is it's not creating the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you define your method in your own class you should remove the `AccelData.` part:

```
public static void WriteToFile(String fileLoc, File accelData) {
    //code in here
}

public static void main(String [ ] args)
{
    String fileLoc = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "AccelData.txt";

    File accelData = new File(fileLoc);

    WriteToFile(fileLoc, accelData); 
}
```

You should not name variables with an initial capital. That is confusing. The same goes for methods. And you do need ta make the methods static.